# How to expand a data frame to from summed to single observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have some Abundance data for Observations of an insect at different dates and places.
And I want to spread the data frame, so that i get one row for each individual insect, that was observed.

```
    set.seed(1234)
    df <- expand.grid(factor = c("A", "B"),
        date = seq(as.Date("2019-05-04"), as.Date("2019-05-08"),"day"))
    df$Abundance <- sample(seq(3,10,1), nrow(df), replace = T)
```

What I have is:

```
    factor       date Abundance
    1       A 2019-05-04         3
    2       B 2019-05-04         7
    3       A 2019-05-05         7
    4       B 2019-05-05         7
    5       A 2019-05-06         9
    6       B 2019-05-06         8
    7       A 2019-05-07         3
    8       B 2019-05-07         4
    9       A 2019-05-08         8
    10      B 2019-05-08         7
```

And now I want to transform the data frame, that it looks like that:

```
     factor       date  Abundance
    1       A 2019-05-04         1
    2       A 2019-05-04         1
    3       A 2019-05-04         1
    4       B 2019-05-04         1
    5       B 2019-05-04         1
    6       B 2019-05-04         1
    7       B 2019-05-04         1
    8       B 2019-05-04         1
    9       B 2019-05-04         1
    10       B 2019-05-04         1

    ...
```

Does anybody know how to do that with dplyr?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See `?tidyr::uncount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `uncount` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
uncount(df, Abundance) %>%
       mutate(Abundance = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rep` and `slice`, where we repeat every row `Abundance` number of times.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), Abundance)) %>%
  mutate(Abundance = 1)


#   factor       date Abundance
#1       A 2019-05-04         1
#2       A 2019-05-04         1
#3       A 2019-05-04         1
#4       B 2019-05-04         1
#5       B 2019-05-04         1
#6       B 2019-05-04         1
#7       B 2019-05-04         1
#8       B 2019-05-04         1
#9       B 2019-05-04         1
#10      B 2019-05-04         1
#....
```

---

Same using base R would be

```
transform(df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$Abundance), ], Abundance = 1)
```